# Create device fingerprint for Ios - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Have to create a Fingerprint for Ios Device.

I have used,

```
gem 'fingerprintjs-rails'
```

It is generating fingerprint based on brower.
But i need fingerprint only based on device data **not based on browser**

Is there any other way to do it.